# Variables are not being replaced using delete operator in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I am facing an issue with variable substitution with Delete operator, my code snippet is

```
let requestData = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);

const dataArray = [
    "client_id",
    "pincode",
    "customer_name",
    "customer_phone",
    "address_type",
    "cod_amount",
    "user_type",
];

let item = pm.globals.get("itemOfArray"); //itemOfArray set to 0 intially
pm.globals.set("varVolume", dataArray[item]);
valfor = pm.globals.get("varVolume");
console.log(valfor);                          //This gives me "client_id"

pm.globals.set("itemOfArray", Number(item) + 1);

delete requestData.valfor;  //Returning true

console.log(valfor);      //Still the output is "client_id"
pm.environment.set('check',JSON.stringify(requestData));
```

My expectation is that when I perform this delete operation "client_id" should get removed from request body.
If I use delete operator like this without variable

```
delete requestData.client_id;
```

then it is working as expected, But I want to run the loop with variable. Please let me know if more details required

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
valfor = "client_id";
delete requestData.valfor;
```

is accessing a property named "valfor", which does not exist.

This is what you want:

```
valfor = "client_id";
delete requestData[valfor];
```

This accesses a property named "client_id".

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem, but still getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
"

Comment: @Raviteja Where is the error occuring, on what line?

Comment: Script is not executed at all, it directly gave Syntax error

Comment: @Raviteja Then you have a syntax error in your code. On what line?

Comment: I am not getting the exact line,

Comment: @Raviteja There are no syntax errors in the code you have provided. Without further information, the problem cannot be found.

Comment: I have added the screenshot, please refer